# Mathematica 11.1 WikipediaData Function cannot receive data from the internet correctly?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wikipedia

I have installed mathematica 11.1 on my linux(Ubuntu 18.04). I learned mathematica for few days, and type the codes with the book"An Elementary Introduction to the wolfram language" by Stephen Wolfram; and the help document.
This problem confuses me: that the Function WikipediaData["Moon"], if it runs correctly it returns the context of the en.wikipedia.com, while I finds this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDBkP.png)

While it runs correctly,it should be that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95qod.png)

I don't kown why. I can enter the wiki website normally, and can not search anything helpful on the internet. So anyone can tell me the reasons, and what I should set Mathematica.

Comment: Some things to try from Mathematica. `PingTime["www.wikipedia.com"]` and `URLRead["www.wikipedia.com"]`. Do they succeed?

Comment: First, thank you for your responding. And I type the `URLRead["www.wikipedia.com"]` as you gived in mathematica, it returns:200 status OK. So mathematica can connect the Wikipedia.com I think. I still don't konw why.

Comment: I hope your help, Thanks.

Comment: Run `PingTime["www.wikipedia.com"]` it returns: 351 ms.

Comment: Hey. I don't konw how to explain that. After I type the Functions("PingTime,URLRead), a few minutes later, I run `WikipediaData["Moon"]`, then it runs correctly. So maybe you let me runs`PingTime` and `URLRead` helped me.  Before this, I have tried for few days, it can not work until now. Thanks. And I'll observe what happen if something useful found I'll share with you. See you.

Comment: That ping time is quite high. 你住了在中国吗？

Comment: Yeah. I'm from China and living for tens of years. So I can't realize "351 ms" is high for me. Generally  how much time that you Run `PingTime`?

Comment: Hey, it is 8:30 pm now. And I'm using computer in my home, I run "URLRead","PingTime" successfully, but Running `WikipediaData["Moon"]`  is still failure to receiving data from the peer. All that happened confuse me.

Comment: `Table[QuantityMagnitude@PingTime@"www.wikipedia.com", 10]` gives `{59.018, 61.835, 56.192, 53.986, 56.431, 58.608, 53.682, 56.88, 57.26, 54.042}`. 我住了在中国一年了. I often had problems with internet connectivity from my apartment.

Comment: OK. I find  it's random that The Function runs correctly。 Now, I can not run it.  By the way, are you living in Beijing or other cities?